# How to solve "Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/PACKAGE"?

Tags: 11.10, apt, update-manager

Whenever I try to update my computer using the Update Manager or `sudo apt-get update` on a terminal  I get this:

```
Failed to download the information from the repository
Check your Internet connection    
Details:    
 `W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ar.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_unive‌rse_i18n_Translation-en`     
  Encountered a section with no Package: header , E:Some index files
  failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

But my Internet connection works fine.

The *banish404* software doesn't work. [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6615120/) is my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

What do I have to do?

Comment: Do you get any messages when you run **sudo apt-get update**?

Comment: @Mitch Yes, the message is the following:  "W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ar.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_unive‌​rse_i18n_Translation-en Encountered a section with no Package: header , E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead"     I explained above..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open your terminal and do as

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ar.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_unive‌​rse_i18n_Translation-en

sudo apt-get update
```

All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you deleted recursively /var/lib/apt/lists, which deleted the partial directory too. So, recreating the directory should solve the issue:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo chmod 755 /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
```

Comment: That wasn't my case, I solved this with [the procedure mentioned above](http://askubuntu.com/a/145000/62483). But if that doesn't help, other may find your solution helpful.